# How to find out the connection limit per user on Postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection

I need to find out if a connection limit has been set on a Postgresql database on a per user basis.

I know you can set such a limit using:

```
ALTER USER johndoe WITH CONNECTION LIMIT 2;
```

Can you check this in the pg_users table?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This information is available in the column rolconnlimit in the view pg_roles
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-roles.html

> *For roles that can log in, this sets maximum number of concurrent connections this role can make. -1 means no limit.*

Answer (score 59):

Whilst connected to the database you want to get this information

```
SELECT rolname, rolconnlimit
FROM pg_roles
WHERE rolconnlimit <> -1;
```

More details are available at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-roles.html

Comment: Note: this will (correctly) return nothing if you don't have any custom roll limits set up.